# JS JSON save current state of a lot of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm making a simulation with a lot of divs (.persons .otherobjects) moving around the screen with .animate() to random locations.

I have to be able to save the current state of the simulation in a JSON array and load this JSON array, and on load, the elements should continue their animation from where they left off.

```
var json = JSON.stringify($('.person'));
```

to stringify the array of persons but im getting the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

and I'm out of ideas after staring at my code for a few hours.

Furthermore, I'm not sure if getting them into an array and converted to JSON would make them keep their animations when loaded back in.

Any comments, ideas, pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to save `$('.person').offset()` or `$('.person').position()`. That is, the _coordinates_ of the div.

Comment: then i wont have his id, animations, name etc when i load it again, is there no way to save the object?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `keep their animations`? You will need to create your own state saving object, how complex that is depends on objectives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a structure like this :

```
var json = {
  "div1" : { top: 212, left: 386 },
  "div2" : { top: 40,  left: 166 },
  "div3" : { top: 20,  left: 218 }
}
```

Each div needs to have its own ID, otherwise, how could you identify them and give them their position back?

Here is how you build your json :

```
var json = {};

$('.person').each( function(){
   json[ $(this).attr('id') ] = $(this).position();
})
```

Then here is how you restore the positions of the divs at load time :

```
$.each( json, function( id, position ){
   $("#"+id).css({ 'top' : position.top , 'left' : position:left })
});
```

Does it make sense?

However, saving their exact state with animation direction and velocity, trajectory etc. seems much harder. Especially if animations are random...

Comment: if my div is at (500,500) and is going towards (800,800) and i save. then when i load it should be at (500,500) and move towards (800,800). so i want to save the animation which must be in some kind of queue or something, im clueless here :S

Comment: Well, when you launch your random animation, you surely randomize the coordinates. Like `randomDestinationX = Math.rand()` or something. So you get your arrival coordinates, don't you? Just save them along with the current coordinates.

Comment: yeah i have my destination too, but then there is the speed, and i would have to calc how far my div is from the original location, and the end location to get the correct speed for the rest of the animation, and i just had a hope there was an easier way of doing that xD

Comment: I just realized, that since they are moving random, i can just load them and call moveRandom( ); and that will be the same result hence they are random -.-